# first derivative test to find where the function is increasing, and decreasing

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have this function: $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{log(x)-1}$$ and I want to find increasing intervals, and decreasing intervals. Here's what I did:

- I've found domain in which the function is defined, and this is what I got: $f: ] 0, +\infty[ (without\space 1)  -> R$.

$0$ and $1$ are critical points in which the function isn't defined (i.e if x = 0, the log is undefined, and if x = 1, the fraction is undefined).

- I've computed first derivative, and this is what I got (I've used quotient rule):
  $$\frac{2x * (log(x) - 1) - x^2 * 1/x}{(log(x)−1)^2}$$
  I've rewritten it, as follows:
  $$\frac{2x * (log(x) - 1) - x}{(log(x)−1)^2}$$
  the denominator is always positive so the sign depends only on the numerator. (I think the problem is in this step)
  on a line, I've chosen 4 different random numbers, $1/4$, $1/2$, $3/2$, $2$, and I've put each number in the first derivative, and this is what I got:
- in the first interval (from 0, to $1/4$), the original function is decreasing (minus sign)
- same for the other intervals

I don't have the full solution of the exercise, therefore I don't knwo if my solution is correct, but I think is strange that in this  function there aren't increasing intervals.

- I think the problem is in the first derivative, but I'm sure I've used the quotient rule correctly.

Comment: Is that a normal notation for the domain? I find it hard to read and understand

Comment: [ , ] stands for closed intervals 
] , [ stands for open intervals, 
] , [ - { } stands for an interval without a point, on this site, I can't use { } because the editor doesn't recognize this parenthesis, so I used  this ( ) instead. 

I thought it were the standard notation

Comment: You might want to look at other numbers, such as $3,4,5,6$.  And $1$ is not a "critical point" though $e$ is.  since $\log_e(1)-1= -1$ but $\log_e(e)-1=0$

Comment: Why do you think it would be appropriate to test random points to find the sign of the first derivative? You apparently haven't found how many times and where it changes sign (do you know how to do that?) What if it changes sign at x=3? Or if you choose to test that number as well, then what about x=4? No finite (or countably infinite) number of test points will be sufficient if you do not know where the function (derivative) changes sign. Also note that you can always graph a function (I recommend the free online website Desmos) to gain insight, this will allow you to verify your solution.

Comment: @Henry That's assuming this is the natural log, which it seems to be based on OP's application of the quotient rule, but perhaps it really is log base 10 and the OP is not aware of how to differentiate "non-natural" logarithms. We can't be sure without OP's verification.

Comment: what does "OP's application" stand for?

Comment: Original Poster, you. You applied quotient rule in a way that suggests that your $log$ is base $e$, I was just cautioning that we should check that is indeed the case, since $log$ often (but not always) represents base $10$, and the derivative would be different in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\log$ stands for the natural logarithm, you can write the derivative as

$$f'(x)=\frac{x(2\log(x)-3)}{(\log(x)-1)^2}.$$

As $x>0$, its sign depends only on the sign of the parenthesis in the numerator and we have that $x<e^{3/2}\implies f'(x)<0$ so the function is decreasing in $]0,1[\cup]1,e^{3/2}[$ and $x>e^{3/2}\implies f'(x)>0$ so it's increasing in $]e^{3/2},+\infty[.$